# HTTPGet is not working

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

```
HttpResponse executeGet(String url) {
    log.error("Inside execute Get");
    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpGet request = null;
    try {
        log.error("Inside execute Get 1");
        request = new HttpGet(url);
        log.error("Inside execute Get 2");
        response = executeHttpRequest(request);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error in HTTP Get : " + ex);
    }
    log.error("Request " + request.toString());
    log.error("Response " + response.toString());
    return response;
}
```

I am calling this method for batching. Only statement "Inside execute Get 1" is being printed in the logs.It's not throwing any exception also. Any help would be appreciated ! :)

Comment: Can you access the URL with a browser; is the server responding?

Comment: Yes the service is up. I tried with HTTPUrlConnection also and that is throwing keystore error as I didn't configure the connection properly. I am using this app in SAP HCP environment. The service is accessible via postman also. It's not related to dependency since, I have all the necessary jar files in place.

Comment: I understand that without proper authentication, I won't have proper response but even in that case also,    response = executeHttpRequest(request); line should throw some error. It seems the app is simply not logging anything anymore once I create the instance of simple HTTPGet (Url)

Comment: The question is really unclear at the moment. So you are accessing an `https` URL without the correct certificates and assuming that it should work?

Comment: I am using all the necessary keymanager,credentialsprovider and trustmanager inside executeHttpRequest. My question is it should at least create the instance of HTTPGet which clearly isn't the case. Otherwise "Inside execute Get 2" would have been printed

Comment: Which `HttpGet` is your code using? Is it something you wrote yourself, something from Apache, or some other 3rd party? If it's an external dependency, which version of the library are you using?

Comment: import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet; I am using 4.5.3 version in pom.xml

Comment: Hi Mick, Thank for taking the time to help . Apparently, it had some issues with the HTTPClient and HTTPCore jar versions. It seems some versions are not compatible with each other and hence they don't behave nicely. Have a nice day :)